# apache2 - How to allow unencrypted access only to local network?

Tags: apache-2.4, linux-networking, virtualhost, http

I have a Linux server on my local network with a few services running. I want to be able to access that server by my domain's name with encryption, but leaving LAN access free. I tried searching for it but it didn't turn up anything. Making another `VirtualHost` with the server's internal IP allowed the external network to connect without encryption.

By the way, is it possible to refuse access to a directory on the same basis?

Edit: I think I'll just go with encrypting everything and not bother with making it accessible by the IP

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Main reason is that SSL forbids access by IPs, and having to type in my entire domain is a hassle

Comment: That's why your browser has a bookmark feature.

Comment: That's true, but sometimes I don't have access to the internet. Also, the DNS server (pihole) is on that device, and if DNS dies, I won't have access to the webGUI to solve it. There's also the second question, as I'd like the DNS' webGUI to not be accessible by anyone outside my network

Comment: what about a simple iptables rule ? ```iptables -A INPUT -s <internal ip range> -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT``` (and drop everything else on that port)

Comment: At first, I thought it will work, but after some thought, this won't work as port 80 won't be forwarded on the router

Comment: if your router doesn't forward incoming connections on port 80 to your linux server, you won't need to do anything - only devices inside your internal network can access the unencrypted port. For any other configuration, the iptables way works quite good...

Comment: The problem is that apache automatically forwards any unencrypted requests to https, even on local IPs. Dropping packets from external networks won't act on this, unless I misunderstand the way it works

Comment: if you simply want to get rid of the ugly certificate warning, add a hosts entry for your local PC, which holds the full domain name using the local IP. That way, TLS is happy, and you're independand from internet access and DNS, and you can access your server locally via bookmark...

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, where solution to the original problem would be a split DNS setup. If you allow unencrypted connections from the local network, you probably just trust your internal network too much.

Comment: @Martin I was thinking about this, and this definitely could work

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I simply didn't forward port 80 on the router, and disabled the http to https redirect on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache's `mod_authz_core` access control commands - this is a core module and you shouldn't need to install or enable anything special.

See a tutorial here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

To use it, set it up in your `<VirtualHost>` under a `<Directory>` section - this instruction must be set in a `<Directory>` so you should have a `<Directory>` section in your `<VirtualHost>` even if you plan on using default directory handling configured elsewhere:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/some/docroot"
    ServerName my.domain.com

    <Directory "/some/docroot">
        <RequireAll>
            Require ip 192.168.1.0/24
        </RequireAll>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This will cause all calls to port 80 from outside your LAN (represented here as 192.168.1.0/24 - change according to your actual LAN address) to receive a `403 Forbidden` response.